# Integral estimate with logarithms

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, inequality, logarithms

> Let $A:=B(0,2\vert x \vert)\,\backslash\,B(0,\frac{\vert x\vert}{2})\subset\mathbb{R}^4$, where $x\neq 0$. Now I have this integral:
> \begin{align*}
> I:=\int_A\log\bigg(\frac{1}{\vert x-y\vert}\bigg)\frac{1}{\vert y\vert^4\vert\log\vert y\vert\vert^{2+\varepsilon}}\mathrm{d}y
> \end{align*}
> and they say that \begin{align*}I\leq\frac{C}{\vert\log\vert x\vert\vert^{1+\varepsilon}}.\end{align*}

I'm reading a paper and I don't know how to get this estimate that the authors say it holds. I tried some logarithmic inequalities but what confuses me are the signs, or
maybe I did some dumb mistake. Thank you in advance for your help!